# Is upgrading MySQL to MariaDB seamless for Drupal sites

Tags: database

My server has an outdated version of MySQL (5.5, which EOL'd in December). The WHM panel has an update option and the recommended upgrade is MariaDB 10.3.

In theory (with all usual "test first" caveats), should a major upgrade like this be seamless for the Drupal sites running on the server?

Comment: You do have to move the database over I would assume. You should do a dry run of this locally with a Docker setup or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal runs fine on both MariaDB and MySQL, so you should be able to replace one with the other without any issues at the application layer (Drupal).  I don't believe the abstraction layer does anything differently between the two so you shouldn't have issues with needing to change field types (swapping to Postgres or other engines Drupal supports would change that answer significantly).

I would expect with an update like that to require some downtime, and a change of username and passwords for the database itself. So you will probably need to update the database connection settings once the update is complete.

All that of course depends on WHM doing the actual update of the database layer correctly so that "test first" caveat is a big deal.

Comment: I was talking this over with a server tech who has indicated they can perform this update with some additional "checks and balances" that will make it possible to roll back if the upgrade causes any problems. But I agree, I'll plan on some downtime in the middle of the night while the update is happening. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else having this question in the future: the upgrade went smoothly with only minor downtime to restart services. Nothing related to the databases needed to be changed (including names, usernames, passwords). But please do take backups prior to upgrading.